Modal dialog is not executing the given function
I checked the similar question already on here but it didn't help.
It's my clickFunc() that doesn't seem to get executed here:
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <select id="players" name="players">
        <option value="Kobe">Kobe</option>
        <option value="LeBron">LeBron</option>
        <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="submitForm()">
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
    function onSuccess() {
      alert("onSuccess");
    }

    function submitForm() {
      let player = document.getElementById('players').value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).clickFunc();
    }
  </script>
</html>

GAS:
function testFunc() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dropdownTest')
      .setWidth(300)
      .setHeight(200);
  const dialog = ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Push the button")  
  Logger.log("TEST");

}

function clickFunc() {
  Logger.log("test")
}

The dialog does get displayed. I select a player then click on the "OK" button. onClick() doesn't seem to work, but the callback function onSuccess() does.

About It's my clickFunc() that doesn't seem to get executed, when I tested your showing script. When I select one of the options and click "ok" button, clickFunc() is run and onSuccess() is run. So, I cannot replicate your issue. And, from but the callback function onSuccess() does., it seems that the function onSuccess() is run. In this case, I think that clickFunc() is also correctly run. How about this? I think that you can check the log of clickFunc() at "Executions" in the script editor.

Are you checking the clickFunc Execution log?

@Tanaike I've checked the execution log and it isn't showing. However, when I placed an ui.alert("Test") on the subsequent line, that did get executed.
It's just the Logger.log("test") that doesn't seem to get logged on the execution log for some reason.

Thank you for replying. In your situation, your browser permits you to open the popup of alert("onSuccess")? For example, when you put console.log("ok") just before the line of alert("onSuccess");, can you confirm ok in the console of the browser?

@Tanaike Yes, the alert("onSuccess") popup does open. I added console.log("ok:) and that showed in the console as well.
I've also added an alert("test") to the line after clickFunc()'s Logger.log("test"), and that gets executed! So now I know clickFunc() does get executed. But Logger.log("test") still won't show in the execution log.

@Tanaike I'm now thinking that Logger.log("test") doesn't show in the execution log, because it isn't clickFunc() I've selected (in App Script IDE) to execute, but instead testFunc(). Then again calling testFunc() calls clickFunc(). So I'm not sure. Could this be?

You are expecting the Execution Log panel shown below. The code in the Google Apps Script editor shows the log written by clickFunc(). Unfortunately, the Execution Log doesn't work that way, you need to open the Executions Logs:

Hover over the left panel to expand the sidebar menu, then click Executions  Logs

or

Go to https://scripts.google.com, find your project on My Projects, All Projects or by searching, then click the three dots button of corresponding entry, then click Execution Logs.

